# Is "System.Web.Helpers.Chart" class MVC or WebForms

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a question about the Chart class of System.Web.Helpers

For a school project, I must use ASP.NET MVC, no WebForms.
I want to have a bar chart in my web page but I'm not sure if the Chart class is MVC or WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that library to render a chart in ASP.NET MVC using razor. See http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart for examples of how to use it in your cshtml files.

You can also use a client side library like Chart.js or JQPlot that are not dependent on your server side implementation.